# How do Ioffe & Szegedy obtain the equation $\frac{\partial \text{BN}((aW)u)}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial\text{BN}(Wu)}{u}$?

Tags: deep-learning

In [the paper that introduced Batch Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), on page 5, the authors write the equation

$$\frac{\partial \text{BN}((aW)u)}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial\text{BN}(Wu)}{u}$$

Here $W$ is the matrix of weights connecting the layer $u$ to the next, batch-normalized layer, so the conclusion is that scaling the weights by a constant doesn't affect this partial derivative.

This seems false to me. Let $b$ be the value of some output neuron and $u$ the layer above, so that:

$$b=\sum w_iu_i$$

Now let $\hat b$ be the batch-normalized version of $b$:

$$\hat b = b - \frac1N\sum b^i$$

where by $b^i$ I mean the value of the neuron $b$ for the $i$-th training input in the batch. We have

$$\hat b = \sum w_iu_i - \frac1N\sum_j b^j= \sum w_iu_i - \frac 1N\sum_j (\sum_i w_ju_j^i)$$

Since the values $u_i$ never appear in the second sum we simply have

$$\partial_{u_i} \hat b = w_i$$

Which very much does scale with $W$. Am I making a mistake, or misinterpreting the original equation?